# What is the default initialization vector behavior for the Java implementation of AES?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

We have a client who is using the Java code below to create a cipher before transmitting us some data:

```
SecretKeySpec localSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(arrayOfByte, "AES");
Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

We're trying to understand how the Initialization Vector is generated for the above when only a key is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sun provider defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding when given the "AES" transformation. ECB mode does not use an initialization vector. Note that ECB is not considered secure.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I'd seen other examples describing AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding but didn't realize ECB in there was the mode. Thanks!